# UIVibrancyEffect On iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

So I've been playing around with the iOS 8 beta and implementing the new UIEffectViews in the places that my app needed them. Now I've run into the issue that I still want to have backwards compatibility for iOS 7, but maintain the vibrancy effect because it really helps readability. I've used UIToolbars in the past for a blur effect, and they work great, but not for vibrancy. I thought I'd subclass UIView and add a toolbar subview and then do some clever rendering to sort of achieve the vibrancy effect which would look like this:
1. render the toolbar to a UIImage
2. render the vibrant content to a UIImage
3. mask the toolbar image to the vibrant content image mask
4. mess with the saturation and brightness
5. have a subview of the UIView display the final result over the toolbar

I've tried doing this in drawRect: of the UIView but it doesn't want to redraw every frame, and setting a timer really messes with animation, even though the render time isn't very high. If anyone can point me to sample code or a open source library, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. For the time being, I've implemented a workaround for iOS 7 where I just "scan through" (convert it to UIImage and calculate the average color) the underlying view to determine if I need to display white or black text on the view. I understand the result isn't the same, but it will work for my purposes. I guess replicating the same vibrancy effect would be a PITA.

Comment: @MarkusRautopuro I ended up just using a toolbar view and rendering the content I wanted to be vibrant to a mask and then just overlay it onto the toolbar. It's not as 'vibrant' as ios8, but it doesn't look bad.

Comment: Okay, sounds like a good approach. Can you share some code by answering your own question?

Comment: @MarkusRautopuro Posted and answer with the code :)

Comment: This probably sounds silly, but can I ask – why are you trying to provide an update that supports iOS 7 too? The App store allows your customers to get hold of your most recent App version compatible with their device (even if it's stuck on iOS 4), and almost all users that can upgrade will upgrade very rapidly. So, unless you are issuing a critical bug fix that you want older OS versions to get (in which case, avoid lots of new UI), my rather dull advice is to just target the latest OS. I'm interested to hear views to the contrary though.

Comment: @Benjohn I know that the latest version of iOS is very quickly adopted. I initially released my app for iOS 7, and I didn't want to lose backwards compatibility. So instead I decided to have it check if the system is iOS 8, and if so, use the vibrancy views from Apple, otherwise it uses my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I never posted an answer, but I did figure it out.

The brute force approach I tried was to use Core Image effects. I would render the superview to a UIImage, blur it, then overlay it on a toolbar with the dark style. This looked great, but even on a GPU context on my 5S, it was pretty slow, so theres no way it would work on other devices. This is the best I could get it to look, and would work great for static content, but is not practical for real-time.

I was able to achieve a real time version, but it doesn't look quite as good. Basically what I do is render all the vibrant content to a image and use it for a mask for a view. Then I make the view barely visible (like .2 alpha), and then put it over a toolbar. It doesn't look quite as vibrant as iOS8, or the original CI version, but it works great and preforms well.

Heres a bit of code you can just copy and paste if you really want:

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
        {

            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.2];

            maskingContents = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
            [self addSubview:maskingContents];
        }

    return self;
}

-(void)addSubview:(UIView *)view
    {

        if (![view isEqual:maskingContents])
        {
            [maskingContents setHidden:NO];

            [maskingContents addSubview:view];

            //now we need to mask it
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0);
            [maskingContents.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

            UIImage* mask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            //apply the mask
            CALayer* maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
            maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
            [maskLayer setContents:(id)mask.CGImage];
            [self.layer setMask:maskLayer];

            [maskingContents setHidden:YES];

        } else [super addSubview:view];
    }

-(void)forceVibrancyUpdate
    {
        [maskingContents setHidden:NO];

        //now we need to mask it
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0);
        [maskingContents.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIImage* mask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        //apply the mask
        CALayer* maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        [maskLayer setContents:(id)mask.CGImage];
        [self.layer setMask:maskLayer];

        [maskingContents setHidden:YES];
    }

@end
```

If you want to dynamically update the content inside the vibrancy view, you would call forceVibrancyUpdate, as that would re-render the mask and apply it. Hope this helped everyone.